# ActiveRecord: Group by count of has_many: through model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Given these classes

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :team_memberships
  has_many :follow_ups, through: :team_memberships
end

class TeamMembership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :follow_ups
end

class FollowUp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team_membership
  has_one :account, through: :team_membership
end
```

I'm looking for the idiomatic way to query in ActiveRecord to get all `Account`s that have more than one incomplete `FollowUp` (i.e. `Account`s that have more than one `FollowUp` with a `completed_at` of `nil`).

A slow way, which uses Ruby but does not compile entirely to SQL, would be

```
Account.all.select do |acc| 
  acc.follow_ups.where(completed_at: nil).count > 1 
end
```

But what's the proper ActiveRecord query for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> query in ActiveRecord to get all Accounts that have more than one incomplete FollowUp

It can be solved just by `join` the `follow_ups` to `accounts` and filtering by the `follow_ups.completed_at`:

```
Account.joins(:follow_ups).where(follow_ups: { completed_at: nil })
```

If you need the number of incomplete `follow_ups` to be more than a particular number, then `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` may help:

```
Account
  .joins(:follow_ups)
  .where(follow_ups: { completed_at: nil })
  .group(:id)
  .having("COUNT(follow_ups.id) > 1")
```

Comment: That's getting close, but I need accounts for which there is *more than one* incomplete follow-up.

Comment: @jayqui then group by and having may help you with it (updated my answer)